# Pivot table custom aggregation function

Tags: excel

I have a table like this in an excel spreadshhet:

```
    Col1    |    Col2   |    Col3
 -----------+-----------+-----------
     A      |     X     |      1
     A      |     Y     |      2
     B      |     X     |      3
     B      |     Y     |      4
     B      |     Z     |      5
```

I want to use the aggregation feature of the pivot table.
Using the typical SUM of VALUES aggregation, provided by Excel, I get:

```
    Col1    |    Col3
 -----------+-----------
     A      |     3
     B      |     12
```

But I want to use a different aggregation function. I want to use something that does:

```
 Square root of ( Sum of (Square(x)))
```

So that in the end I get the table:

```
    Col1    |    Col3
 -----------+-----------
     A      |     SQRT(5)      <= Sqrt(1*1 + 2*2)
     B      |     SQRT(50)     <= Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4 + 5*5)
```

Is there ANY way (VBA, C++, assembly, whatever it takes) I can specify my own functions in the aggregation list?

**NOTE: I KNOW HOW TO DO THIS IN A SHEET, DON'T BOTHER ANSWERING IF IT'S NOT ABOUT WRITING CUSTOM AGGREGATION FUNCTIONS FOR PIVOTTABLE**

Comment: Since you know how to do it manually, could you create a macro?

Comment: Well not really. Thing is you can create pivot table straight from recordset or other funky sources that you don't need to spread on the sheet... Thx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to write a custom aggregation function for a standard pivot table. But you can probably do what you want using MDX... maybe an MDX expert would like to comment?

Comment: You would have to build an OLAP cube from the numbers in the spreadsheet first, before you could use MDX. But OLAP does have custom aggregation methods, yes.